# Вывод сообщений постранично

Tags: php, mysql

Всем привет. Такая проблема: Не получается сделать навигацию на php.

В общем ситуация такая: Существует страница, где есть две ГЕТ переменные $_GET['id'] и $_GET['page']
Первая переменная отвечает за id пользователя, ее может не быть (При отсутствие указывает свою страницу). Вторая переменная отвечает за вывод сообщений из базы. Вот в чем заключается мой вопрос: Как добавлять к $_GET['page']+10 ,но при этом не терять $_GET['id'], а если и нет переменной $_GET['id'], то указывать только $_GET['page'] и прибавлять 10.

Пример: http://site.com/index.php?id=5&page=20 или http://site.com/index.php?page=20
Генерировать ссылку необходимо в линк <a href="Сгерерированный линк">ТЕСТ</a>

Вроде бы все логично, но не получается.Кто знает, как реализовать? За ранее спасибо.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Я обычно использую свою функцию-велосипед:

```
function formGet($str, $k, $v = ''){
    if(is_array($k))
        foreach($k as $k2 => $v2)
            $str = formGet($str, $k2, $v2);
    else
        if(!strlen($str))
            $str .= '?&'.$k.'='.$v;
        else
        {
            if(strpos($str, '?') === false)
                $str .= '?&'.$k.'='.$v;
            else
                if(preg_match('/&?'.$k.'=/', $str))
                    $str = preg_replace('/(&)?'.$k.'=[^&]+/', '$1'.$k.'='.$v, $str);
                else
                    $str .= '&'.$k.'='.$v;
        }
    return $str;
}
if(!isset($_GET['page']) || $_GET['page'] < 10) $_GET['page'] = 10;
$link = formGet($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], 'page', $_GET['page']+10);
```

Comment: Спасибо. Но все же работает не много не правильно. Допустим если ссылка такая <a href="/profile/<?=$link?>">test</a>
то формируется ссылка http://site.com/profile/profile?id=5&page=20 ,
Если убрать в ссылке profile <a href="/<?=link?>">test</a> , то формируется ссылка http://site.com/?id=5&page=20 а вот найти, от чего это зависит я не смог.

Comment: Ну, правильно. Функция не трогает пути ссылок - только get-параметры.

Comment: Тогда же почему она дублирует в ссылке "profile/profile?id=5..."?

Comment: Потому что у вас в href'е ссылки дописывается еще один profile.

Comment: если не дописывать profile : sait.com/?id=5&page=20
Возможно profile считает $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']

Comment: Ага, в $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] содержится все, что после хоста. А вот уже $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'] содержит только строку запроса.

Comment: Спасибо. Разобрался. За место $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] лучше всего вставить "?".$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']